# Need to scrape glassdoor company reviews from aws server (windows or linux)

Tags: python, web-scraping

I have tried web scraping of glassdoor company reviews using beautiful soup, selenium, mechanical soup, and gazpacho in all libraries when i ran it from my local i was able to scrape. But the same code when I was trying to run from my AWS ec2 instance i was facing the 403 forbidden error. However my expectation is to run the code from the server. I have two ec2 instance one linux and one is windows in both of them Iam facing a same error

tried this code snippet returns

> 403 forbidden error

```
import urllib.request

user_agent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (platform; rv:geckoversion) Gecko/geckotrail Firefox/firefoxversion'

url = "https://www.glassdoor.co.in/Reviews/Wells-Fargo-Reviews-E8876.htm"

request = urllib.request.Request(url)

request.add_header('User-Agent', user_agent)

response = urllib.request.urlopen(request)

#print(response.read())

with open('Output_new.txt', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:

    print(response.read(), file=f)
```

while running this code I get 403 tried to add more headers

I also tried it using `gazpacho libraries get method`

here:

```
url = 'https://www.glassdoor.co.in/Reviews/Wells-Fargo-Reviews-E8876.htm'

html = get(url)

soup = Soup(html)

print(soup)

with open('Output.txt', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:

    print(soup, file=f)
```

here also I am facing the same error

Can anyone please help me with this issue

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

From the [Glassdoor Terms of Use](https://www.glassdoor.com/about/terms.htm):

> You agree that you will not:
>
> - Introduce software or automated agents to Glassdoor, or access Glassdoor so as to produce multiple accounts, generate automated messages, or to scrape, strip or mine data from Glassdoor without our express written permission;

I think your basic issue here isn't necessarily technical - it's that you're violating the Terms of Use of this site, which is clearly well equipped to frustrate your efforts. The right answer here is probably to stop trying to scrape Glassdoor.

I've run into this dilemma more than once myself with sites from which I wanted to scrape data. At the end of the day its probably best to respect the expressed wishes of the site owners, whatever they may be. After all, they make their money and pay their employees because they have data others don't - and for that reason they protect it.